# Spring Data JPA - extends class fields issue

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a class 'Source' with sourceid field. 'SourceName' class has sourceName field which can be reused for other classes also, so i created a new class instead of repeating this field in each class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SOURCE")
public class Source extends SourceName{

    @Id
    @Column(name="SOURCEID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer sourceid;

    public Integer getSourceid() {
        return sourceid;
    }

    public void setSourceid(Integer sourceid) {
        this.sourceid = sourceid;
    }
}

public class SourceName {

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "SOURCENAME")
    private String sourcename;

    public String getSourcename() {
        return sourcename;
    }
    public void setSourcename(String sourcename) {
        this.sourcename = sourcename;
    }
}

@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> add(@RequestBody SourceName sourceName) {

    Source source = new Source();
    source.setSourcename("somevalue");

    sourceRepository.save(source);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Table: ('sourcename' field cannot be NULL and cannot assign a default value)

```
CREATE TABLE `SOURCE` (
  `sourceid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sourcename` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sourceid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `sourcename_UNIQUE` (`sourcename`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

It's working fine if i keep sourcename field directly under 'Source' class:

```
Hibernate: insert into source (sourcename) values (?)
```

Getting below error if i keep sourcename in 'SourceName' class.  Am i doing anything wrong ?

```
Hibernate: insert into source values ( )    
SqlExceptionHelper   : Field 'sourcename' doesn't have a default value
```

Comment: post the DDL for your table. If you have objects of type `Source` then the column that stores "sourcename" has to allow NULLs or have a default defined in the DDL.

Comment: updated my post with created table statement. There is no default value for 'sourcename' and it should not allow NULLs. This table is used by Admin to feed Source values. So I can't assign a default value.

Comment: I deleted the answer as it wasn't helpful :-(

Comment: Well unless the root class is annotated as an entity or mapp superclass it wont work. But the jpa docs will tell you that

Comment: yes, issue resolved by @MappedSuperclass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use annotation `javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass` on the Super class `SourceName` and try.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class SourceName {
...
}
```